# show GKGameCenterViewController in SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-center, viewcontroller, skscene

I struggling with the following Problem:

I've made a game with SpriteKit. I implemented the `GameCenter` to my game. It works. Player logs in automatically and the highscore will be added to the default Leaderboard. But for example in the "EndScreen" I want to show the `GameCenterLeaderboard`.

Appledocumentation tells me that I should use the following code:

```
- (void) showGameCenter

{

GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

if (gameCenterController != nil)

{

gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];

}

}
```

But `presentViewController` does not work. Is there any way to switch from a `SKScene` to my standard `ViewController`. Or how can I show up the `GameCenterleaderboard` with a button touched?

To be honest I'm pretty new to programming so this issue here might not a big problem to solve for you guys.
Big big thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is a way, you can call this code directly from `-(void)showGameCenter`:

```
  UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
  [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use notification to tell `ViewController` to show a leaderboard.

`ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation GameSceneViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(showGameCenter)
                                                 name:@"ShowLeaderboard"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

.....
```

`SKScene.m`:

```
- (void)showLeaderboard {    
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
             postNotificationName:@"ShowLeaderboard"
                           object:nil
                         userInfo:nil];
}
```